# Orthogonality condition for two complex-valued vectors $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^n$, iff $\operatorname{Re}\left\{a^* b \right\}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am sorry for asking a basic question.

> Orthogonality condition for the two complex-valued vectors $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is iff $\operatorname{Re}\left\{a^* b \right\} = 0$?

---

I thought the orthogonality condition is $\langle a, b \rangle = a^Hb = 0$. If my understanding is correct, then how $$\operatorname{Re}\left\{a^* b \right\} = 0$$ should be true to ensure orthogonality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think of $a\in\mathbb{C}$ like a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ 
$$a = u + iv \sim \begin{bmatrix} u \\ v\end{bmatrix}, \ b = w + iz \sim \begin{bmatrix} w \\z\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $<a,b> := uw + vz$ and $a^*b = uw + vz + i(uz - vw)$; therefore
$$<a,b> = 0 \iff Re(a^*b) = 0$$

Similarly if $a,b\in \mathbb{C}^n$, you may take $u,v,w,z\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then
$$<a,b> := u\cdot w + v\cdot z $$
and
$$(a^*)^Tb = (u-iv)\cdot(w + iz) = u\cdot w + v\cdot w + i(u\cdot z - v\cdot w)$$
Therefore
$$<a,b>  = 0 \iff Re((a^*)^Tb)=0$$